# $\|\omega_{\xi}-\omega_{\eta}\| = |\|\xi\|^2-\|\eta\|^2|$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Given $\xi \in H$, consider
$$\omega_\xi: B(H) \to \mathbb{C}: x \mapsto \langle x \xi, \xi\rangle.$$

Do we have $\|\omega_{\xi}-\omega_{\eta}\| = |\|\xi\|^2-\|\eta\|^2|$ for $\xi, \eta \in H?$. It is easy to see that we have the inequality $$|\|\xi\|^2 - \|\eta\|^2| \le \|\omega_\xi-\omega_\eta\|$$
but I'm having a hard time proving the converse inequality. I'm beginning to suspect the converse inequality is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your equality were true, any two $\omega_\xi$ and $\omega_\eta$ would be multiples of each other.

For an easy counterexample let $H=\mathbb C^2$, and take $\xi=(1,0)$, $\eta=(0,1)$. Then $\|\xi\|^2-\|\eta\|^2=0$, while
$$
(\omega_\xi-\omega_\eta)\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\ b&d\end{bmatrix} =a-d,
$$
with $\|\omega_\xi-\omega_\eta\|=2$.